# Dumb question : under the assumption of the normal distribution and using log return stationarity

Tags: log-returns, mean-reversion

Under the assumption of the normal distribution, I'm  trying to create a single stock mean reversion strategy. I took the log returns because they are stationary, I standardized them and used the zscore as trading signals(buy when zscore is -2, take gains when the zscore is 0, sell when zscore is +2 and take gains when zscore goes to 0. This strategy comes from Ernest chan's books and blogs.

I backtested it and the results are good. But I'm unsure about the statistical logic behind it.

Moreover I did not find any serious research paper about  this strategy, and Ernest Chan's books don't really detail why he uses the Zscore.

Does this strategy makes sense or is it dumb, and why ?

Comment: I'm not sure the assumption about the log-returns being stationary is valid. Looking at this I am seeing a lot of changing slopes, so you may be getting varying results based on underlying asset and time period.  Look to see if you are getting a lot more buy signals than sell signals.

Comment: Well I just checked quickly, I would say it's almost 50-50 on average across all the stocks I tested.

Comment: When you compute the z-score, do you do it on the whole dataset, or on a rolling basis?

Comment: The question is not well posed. Are you working in a price space or a return space? How are you determining your time frames? What types of markets are you in? How liquid, particularly depth, is the market you are in? Pluggin in a parameter to a z-score can always be dominated by other techniques, so do you have an opponent that can take advantage of you? Step by step, what is your behavior. What kind of measurements are you taking, when and why?

Comment: – rubikscube09 . I do it on the whole data set

Comment: – Dave Harris. Return space. My time frame is determined by the number of trades. I wanted as much trades as possible so I used a 1 day perdiod with interval of 1 minutes accros a year.

Comment: "– Dave Harris. Pluggin in a parameter to a z-score can always be dominated by other techniques, so do you have an opponent that can take advantage of you?" Well, faster algos will crush me. and for the other questions, I did not think that far. But I thank you for showing me how unclear I was. I will give more details next time I ask a question.  I was basically trying to find a mean reversion strategy for single stocks, but I don't think it exists. I wanted to find something else than the technical analysis moving average, as I don't believe it works.

Comment: I'm just a beginner with quantitative trading. I started a few months ago. If you have other strategies in mind(research papers, books) I could try, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any statistical basis for the phenomenon of mean reversion. It really defies the rule of independence which is usually part of statistical methods.  Other than that, it is also counter to momentum investing which go against precisely what you are intending to do. Countering that with the positive skew of long term stock price movement, I think that you might make some money from it, but would be much less that what you would make with trend following. Also you would be subject to the same risks as the general stock market. I would only trade it with stop losses.

Comment: I see. Indeed this strategy has no statistical value. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome.  Indeed, the 'dumbest questions' are sometimes the one's that make you rethink the status quo.